# Google Chrome Frame in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, browser, controls, frame

I need to load a website in a application, and this website only works with Google Chrome

After I install Google Chrome Frame I saw i have a new Reference:
`ChromeTabLib`

I'm trying to use it, but I don't know how.

Does someone know how I can use a Browser Control with Google Chrome Frame in Visual Basic.net?

UPDATE: I tried to use Webkit but the website doesnt works with Webkit. LOL

UPDATE2: I added ChromeFrame COM tool, and when I drop on the form, i get:
[This message](http://fotos.subefotos.com/e1136899e41415ebe3d51ef7c092e123o.png)

Comment: You should use WebKit directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably will need to use WebKit instead. WebKit drives Chrome. There are a few open source options.

**This one looks very promising: [WebKit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/). It has fairly active [forums](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/forums/forum/939856).**

> WebKit .NET is a control library wrapper for WebKit written in C#. The
>   aim is to make it easy for users to incorporate WebKit into their .NET
>   applications.

Here is a promising [tutorial](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php). From the tutorial:

> To use the control in the designer, right click the toolbox and select
>   Choose Items -> .NET Framework Components. Click 'Browse...', navigate
>   to the WebKit .NET directory and select WebKitBrowser.dll. The
>   WebKitBrowser control should appear in the list as below

You can use the control's navigate function to load a page:

```
private sub button1_Click(byref sender as object, byval e as EventArgs)
    webKitBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text)
end sub
```

**Related Question**: [Google chrome control for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534843/google-chrome-control-for-net)

Comment: I tried to use Webkit but the website doesnt works with Webkit. LOL

Comment: I added ChromeFrame COM tool, and when I drop on the form, i get: [This message](http://fotos.subefotos.com/e1136899e41415ebe3d51ef7c092e123o.png)